# To penetrate something, but not physically. Can I use "penetrate" figuratively?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, pronouns

> Light and space. These two factors penetrate themselves mutually and complement each other.

I do not know if verb penetrate can be used while describing the features of material. I mean penetrate  not physically but rather metaphorically. Also I had got difficulty with using themselves and each other....

Comment: You'd better provide some context, roka, at least by mentioning the general field to which this sentence is expected to belong. A particular word befitting a physics article might look awkard inside an article dedicated to interior design. For interior design, I'd pick a verb like "interact".

Answer (score 4):

When you speak figuratively, not literally, you're pretty free to say anything you like. If it makes sense to other people and is a 'happy' way of expressing what you mean, it's fine.

However, we would not say that light and space *penetrate themselves*—that would mean that light penetrates light and space penetrates space, which doesn't seem to me to make sense. What you appear to mean is expressed by *each other*, exactly as you use it in the second predicate, *complement each other*.

If you are anxious to avoid using *each other* twice in a row you could say

> The two factors *interpenetrate* and complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

- suffuse
  http://i.word.com/idictionary/suffuse
- permeate
  http://i.word.com/idictionary/permeate
- pervade
  http://i.word.com/idictionary/pervade

Or various near-synonyms from a Thesaurus:

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/permeating